# MySqli prepared statment doesn't use updated variable value when executing the statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

My prepared statement isn't using the updated value while executing , it's using the one i set before binding , is this how it should work? because in examples on w3schools it was using updated value, so i'm not sure what am i doing wrong here, under //winner comment is problematic part, $assqlst2 isn't using updated value of $pointswon(I put that echo just to make sure values are correct, and i'm not getting any errors in output).

```
<?php 
$dbserver = ""; //database information is populated in my script, i didn't put it here because of security resons.
$dbusername = "";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "";  
$dbrecievedPassword = $_POST['dbPassword'];
$winnerid = intval($_POST['winnerid']);
$winnername = $_POST['winnername'];
$pointswon = intval($_POST['pointswon']);
$loserid = intval($_POST['loserid']);
$losername = $_POST['losername'];
$pointsph = $pointswon;
if($dbrecievedPassword != null && $dbrecievedPassword == $dbpassword) {
    echo "PWD_OK";
}
else {
    echo "PWD_INCORRECT";
}

$conn = new mysqli($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbrecievedPassword);
mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname);
if($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: ".connect_error);
}
if($winnerid != null) {
    if($sqlst = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE uid=?")) {
        if($assqlst2 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE table_name SET as_points=? WHERE as_uid=?")) {
            if($sqlst3 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name (as_uid,as_points,as_username) VALUES (?,?,?)")) {

                $sqlst->bind_param("i",$winnerid);
                $assqlst2->bind_param("ii",$pointswon,$winnerid);

                $sqlst3->bind_param("iis",$winnerid,$pointswon,$winnername);
                if($loserid != null) {
                    //winner

                    if(!$sqlst->execute()) {
                        echo $conn->error;
                    }
                    $sqlst->bind_result($b1,$b2,$b3);
                    $sqlst->fetch();
                    $pointswon = $pointsph + intval($b3);
                    echo $pointswon." ".$winnerid;
                    if(!$assqlst2->execute()) {
                        echo $conn->error;
                    }
                    //loser
                    $winnerid = $loserid;
                    if(!$sqlst->execute()) {
                        echo $conn->error;
                    }
                    $sqlst->bind_result($c1,$c2,$c3);
                    $sqlst->fetch();
                    $pointswon = intval($c3) - $pointsph;
                    $sqlst->close();
                    if(!$assqlst2->execute()) {
                        echo $conn->error;
                    }
                    $assqlst2->close();

                }else {
                    if(!$sqlst->execute()) {
                        echo $conn->error;
                    }
                    $sqlst->bind_result($k1,$k2,$k3);
                    $sqlst->fetch();
                    if($k1 != null) {
                        $pointswon = intval($pointsph) + intval($k3);
                        $sqlst->close();
                        if(!$assqlst2->execute()) {
                            echo $conn->error;
                        }
                        $assqlst2->close();

                    }else {
                        $pointswon = $pointsph;
                        $sqlst3->execute();
                        $sqlst3->close();
                    }
                }
            }else {
                echo $conn->error;
            }
        }else {
            echo $conn->error;
        }
    }else {
        echo $conn->error;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: I think you have to separate them each, and does it really have to be nested?

Comment: @LoganWayne What do you mean? How do i seperate what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it really have to be nested?

You can't just rehash a query and use it multiple times. If you want to, you just have to put it in a function, so you just have to call it when you want it:

```
function query1($conn, $winnerid){

    if($sqlst = $conn->prepare("SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table_name WHERE uid = ?")){
        $sqlst->bind_param("i", $winnerid);
        $sqlst->execute();
        $sqlst->bind_result($b1, $b2, $b3);
        $sqlst->fetch();
        $sqlst->close();
    }

    return array($b1, $b2, $b3);

}

function query2($conn, $pointswon, $id){

    if($assqlst2 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE table_name SET as_points = ? WHERE as_uid = ?"))
        $assqlst2->bind_param("ii", $pointswon, $id);
        $assqlst2->execute();
        $assqlst2->close();
    }

}

function query3($conn, $winnerid, $pointswon, $winnername){

    if($sqlst3 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name (as_uid,as_points,as_username) VALUES (?,?,?)")){
        $sqlst3->bind_param("iis", $winnerid, $pointswon, $winnername);
        $sqlst3->execute();
        $sqlst3->close();
    }

}
```

After setting the functions, we can now proceed with what you want to achieve:

```
if($winnerid != NULL){

    /*** WINNER UPDATE ***/
    list($b1, $b2, $b3) = query1($conn, $winnerid); /* CALL THE SELECT QUERY */

    if($loserid != NULL){
        $pointswon = $pointsph + intval($b3); /* POINTS GATHERED BY THE WINNER */
        echo $pointswon." ".$winnerid;
    } /* END OF CONDITION $loserid IS NOT NULL */

    query2($conn, $pointswon, $winnerid); /* CALL THE UPDATE QUERY */


    /*** LOSER UPDATE ***/
    list($c1, $c2, $c3) = query1($conn, $loserid); /* CALL THE SELECT QUERY */

    $pointswon = intval($c3) - $pointsph; /* POINT GATHERED BY THE LOSER */

    query2($conn, $pointswon, $loserid); /* CALL THE UPDATE QUERY */


} /* END OF CONDITION $winnerid IS NOT NULL */

else {

    list($k1, $k2, $k3) = query1($conn, $winnerid); /* CALL THE SELECT QUERY */

    if($k1 != null){

        $pointswon = intval($pointsph) + intval($k3);

        query2($conn, $pointswon, $winnerid); /* CALL THE UPDATE QUERY */

    } else {

        query3($conn, $winnerid, $pointsph, $winnername); /* CALL THE INSERT QUERY */

    }

} /* END OF ELSE */
```

Comment: Wow you actually wrote whole code, thank you very much I understand it now :D

Comment: *You can't just rehash a query and use it multiple times.* Where did you learn that? I'm pretty sure you can use a prepared query as many times as you want. `bind_param` binds to variable references, so it's supposed to use the current value of the variables as he expects.

Comment: @Barmar so what is then acctually wrong with my code ?

Comment: @Barmar is there something wrong with my code or is it a bug in php ?

Comment: @Warix3 I don't see anything obvious. But it seems to me that you could do the whole thing with a single MySQL UPDATE statement, rather than doing so much of it in PHP.